# Installing imagehash with pip; Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 required

Tags: python, c++, windows-10

I'm trying to install [ImageHash](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ImageHash) on Win10 64x and Python 3.4.3 by running `pip install imagehash`. However, I get an error:

```
Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279
```

When I get that package, it says I have .Net framework 4 already installed, ok fine. But then I get to the Installation Options page and it says I DON'T have .Net Framework 4, so it won't let me install the Visual C++ Compilers! I download the .Net Framework 4 installer but it says I do have it installed already, so I'm at a loss.

From another answer, I did try setting my `VS100COMNTOOLS` to `VS140COMNTOOLS` but that didn't affect anything.